# Stream with Servant and mtl style

Tags: haskell, servant

I have the following endpoint defined using [servant](https://docs.servant.dev/en/stable/):

```hs
type ServiceAPI = "maintenance" :> Get '[PlainText] Text

myServer ::
     MonadIO m
  => MonadLog m
  => MonadMetrics m
  => MonadRandom m
  => Config
  -> Client
  -> ServerT ServiceAPI m
myServer cfg client = ...
```

The content is sometimes too big to be returned immediately and the HTTP request times out. I would like to transformed this service into some kind of stream-based response. Something similar to:

```hs
type ServiceAPI = "maintenance" :> StreamGet NewlineFraming PlainText (SourceIO Text) -- or SourceT m Text
```

However, I do not understand / figure out how to update the `myServer` to play nicely with the streaming `SourceIO` (`SourceT m`). I believe it cannot be with `SourceIO` because `type SourceIO = SourceT IO` and here we have some other monad stacks.

- How can I stream the content of this response?
  (If `Text` makes things difficult, I can work also with `[Text]`, but the `MonadIO` may complain that `MonadIO does not have an instance for (MonadIO [])` or similar). (Thanks!)

Comment: Tongue in cheek style comment: putting the arrows at the end of the line (as in `MonadIO m =>\nMonadLog m =>\n`) is objectively superior. That way a `=>` on the line means it's a constraint, and a `->` on the line means it's an argument that must be supplied. It's possible to say a similar thing about the way it is now, but to me the analagous thing seems more convoluted; in the current way, `=>` on the line means the rest of the type is the result of proving some constraint, and `->` on the line means the rest of the type is the result of supplying some argument.

Comment: IIRC, having multiple `=>` in that way is a "quirk" of the GHC parser but not explicitly allowed in the language specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need a `SourceT m Text`. Looking in [`Servant.Types.SourceT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18.3/docs/Servant-Types-SourceT.html#t:SourceT), the definition is

```
newtype SourceT m a = SourceT
    { unSourceT :: forall b. (StepT m a -> m b) -> m b
    }
```

So, we are *given* a consumer function `StepT m Text -> m b`, and we need to pass a `StepT m Text` to it.

We may ask, why doesn't Servant require `StepT m Text` directly, instead of this continuation-passing definition? The answer is that the continuation-passing definition lets you insert [`bracket`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket)-like operations that, for example, open a file at the beginning and ensure the file is closed once streaming is finished.

A possible problem I see with your signature is that the constraints do not support bracket-like operations. You need something like [`MonadUnliftIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-core-0.2.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Unlift.html) or [`MonadMask`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.4/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#v:bracket) for that. `MonadIO` is not enough.

Assuming that your monad has an instance of `MonadUnliftIO`, then you could stream a `Text` file like this:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Monad.IO.Unlift -- from "unliftio-core"
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.IO
import Servant.API
import Servant.Server
import Servant.Types.SourceT
import System.FilePath
import System.IO

serveText :: forall m. MonadUnliftIO m => FilePath -> SourceT m Text
serveText filePath = SourceT $ \consumer ->
  withRunInIO $ \unlift ->
    withFile filePath ReadMode $ \handle -> do
      let steps :: StepT m Text
          steps =
            Effect
              ( do
                  eof <- liftIO $ hIsEOF handle
                  if eof
                    then pure Stop
                    else do
                      line <- liftIO $ Data.Text.IO.hGetLine handle
                      pure (Yield line steps) -- recurse for more lines
              )
      -- we get down to IO to satisfy the signature of withFile,
      -- the withRunInIO brings us back to m
      unlift (consumer steps)
```

(Be careful of a naive use of `hGetLine` because it uses the default encoding of the system. Something like [`streamDecodeUtf8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.5.0/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:streamDecodeUtf8) could be better in practice.)

Some notes:

- Only monads isomorphic to `ReaderT` can be instances of `MonadUnliftIO`, and yours might not fit the pattern. Perhaps it's a `MonadMask`.
- Perhaps, instead of using classic `bracket`, or `withField`, you could try using the [resourcet](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.2.4.3) package.
- There are adapters for popular streaming libraries that free you from having to define the `StepT` directly.

Comment: I am going to accept this as a valid answer, because it is more detailed than the solution that I will post below. I still want to add how I solved it in case it helps other people. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As always, the answer lies in how you are trying to type it.
We want to return a stream, for which we update the type of the `ServiceAPI` as follows:

```
type ServiceAPI = "maintenance" :> StreamGet NewlineFraming PlainText (SourceIO Text)
```

The type of `myServer` stays exactly the same. Since I am new to `servant`, I didn't realise that what we want to return is a `SourceT IO Text` in whatever the body of `myServer` computes.
To better see the types, let's assume that `myServer` body calls function `myFunc` as follows, where `myFunc` was before returning `Text` or `[Text]` (this solution works for both with minimal refactoring efforts).

```
myServer ::
     MonadIO m
  => MonadLog m
  => MonadMetrics m
  => MonadRandom m
  => Config
  -> ServerT ServiceAPI m
myServer cfg = myFunc cfg

myFunc ::
     MonadIO m
  => MonadLog m
  => Config
  -> m (SourceT IO Text)
myFunc cfg client = do
  ...
  let ls = _ :: [Text] -- some [Text]
  pure $ source ls
```

The realisation is that we do not want `myFunc` to return `SourceT m Text` but `m (SourceT IO Text)`. One of the missing pieces is that `source :: [a] -> SourceT n a` and that we want `n = IO`, such that we can return `SourceIO = SourceT IO`.

(My mistake was in understanding the return type of `myFunc` as `SourceT m Text`, when it should have been `m (SourceT IO Text)`, and quite correctly, the type checker was disallowing this)